# Why is my d3.tool tip not working for the two of the lines?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization, linechart

The below is the codes that will be used to create the line charts. But the problem I am facing is that my d3.tool tip for the lines are not working accordingly. Also, I would like to be able to shorten the y-axis so that the lines will look to have a bigger gap in between.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
      display: black    ;
    }

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;

    }

    h3 {
      margin-left:220px;
    }
    .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    </style>
    <div>
        <h3>Life Expectancy History</h3>

    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <script>
    var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Male:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.male + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.rankmale;
      });

    var tip1 = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Female:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.female + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.rankfemale;
      });

    var tip2 = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Both Gender:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.both + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.rankall;
      }); 
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var y1= d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var y2= d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(10);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.male); });

        var line2 = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.female); });

        var line3 = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.both); });     

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.call(tip).call(tip1).call(tip2);

        d3.json("lifehistory.json", function (error, data) {
            data.forEach(function (d)
            {
                d.year   = parseDate(d.year.toString());
                d.male  = +d.male;
                d.female = +d.female;
                d.both = +d.both;
            });

            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.year; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.male; })]);
            y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.female; })]);
            y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.both; })]);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
              .attr("x", 265)
              .attr("y", 240)
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text("Years");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Life Expectancy History");


            svg.selectAll('.yaxis1')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'yaxis1')
                    .attr('cx', function(datum){return x(datum.year)})
                    .attr('cy', function(datum){return y(datum.male)})
                    .attr('r', 3)
                    .attr('fill', 'red')
                    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

            svg.selectAll('.yaxis2')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'yaxis2')
                    .attr('cx', function(datum){return x(datum.year)})
                    .attr('cy', function(datum){return y1(datum.female)})
                    .attr('r', 3)
                    .attr('fill', 'blue') 
                    .on('mouseover', tip1.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip1.hide);

            svg.selectAll('.yaxis3')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'yaxis3')
                    .attr('cx', function(datum){return x(datum.year)})
                    .attr('cy', function(datum){return y2(datum.both)})
                    .attr('r', 3)
                    .attr('fill', 'blue')   
                    .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip2.hide);

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                 .style("stroke", "red")
                .attr("d", line(data));

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line2(data));

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line3(data));
        });
    </script></div>
```

This is the line chart that I have created. The d3.tool tip is not working as what I would like as only one the the d3.tool tip is working on one line but the others are not appearing on the other lines. I would like to show the y-axis to have a bigger gap between each of the value and in other words, it means that the gap between lines will be bigger so that people can easily analysis the graph. Is there any method for me to do it that way?

[image: Life Expectancy]

This is the JSON file that I am using.

```
[{"year":"1960","male":"61.7","female":"65.7","both":"63.7","rankmale":"47","rankfemale":"50","rankall":"45"},
{"year":"1970","male":"65.4","female":"70.2","both":"67.7","rankmale":"45","rankfemale":"45","rankall":"44"},
{"year":"1980","male":"68.9","female":"74.2","both":"71.5","rankmale":"33","rankfemale":"36","rankall":"29"},
{"year":"1990","male":"71.9","female":"76.9","both":"74.3","rankmale":"28","rankfemale":"30","rankall":"30"},
{"year":"2000","male":"76.1","female":"80.1","both":"78.1","rankmale":"11","rankfemale":"24","rankall":"15"},
{"year":"2011","male":"80.1","female":"84.6","both":"82.3","rankmale":"6","rankfemale":"8","rankall":"5"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is from using different y scales for tooltips. You used the same y scale for the lines so they appear fine. But when you use different y scales for the circles, they will be plotted differently. So instead of having

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

var y1= d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

var y2= d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);
```

and

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.male; })]);
y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.female; })]);
y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.both; })]);
```

you can just use

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```

and

```
y.domain([50, 90]);
```

And then just use the same y scale when you add the circles.

Notice that I also replace your domain start value from 0 to 50. This will help shortening the y scale and space out your lines.

You can see a live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/B6cUS/

Comment: Is it possible for it to have like a bigger space in between all the lines as the lines are quite close to each other.

Comment: You can manipulate the domain of the scale to do that. In this case, it's safe to use up to [60, 85] for the domain.

Comment: A very good read about D3 Scale and Color is http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/.